# Why does ToString not always return the full file path of IO.FileInfo (when it has been set by calling DirectoryInfo.GetFiles)

Tags: vb.net

> Here's the short story:
>
> A FileInfo created from a full string path returns a full path when .ToString is called.
>
> A FileInfo created using a DirectoryInfo.GetFiles returns just the filename when .ToString is called.
>
> Why is this? Is there a way to make them return the same value without resorting to .FullName or .Name?

.

Here's the long story:

I was under the impression that "IO.FileInfo" when it contained a full file path, would return that full path string when .ToString was called.

*NB I understand that .FullName will also return the full path but my reasons for using ToString are important and are explained below*

> Create folder "C:\Test" and inside that create "file.txt"

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices 'I think this is the one you need to make extensions work but it's too late to make a new project just to test this bit
```

> Place in sub:

```
'Declare file item explicitly
Dim f As New FileInfo("C:\Test\file.txt")
Debug.Print(f.ToString) 'Returns C:\Test\file.txt

'Declare directory and get array of files
Dim d As New DirectoryInfo("C:\Test")
Dim fs As FileInfo() = d.GetFiles()
For each fi as FileInfo in fs
    Debug.Print(fi.ToString) 'Returns file.txt
Next
```

I'm wondering what the reason is for fi.ToString returning a different value to f.ToString - both represent a single instance of FileInfo. I just don't know how the GetFiles' FileInfo creation procedure differs from my own.

My reason for using ToString instead of FullName in this case is this: I've created an extension which checks if a List(Of T) contains an item based on its ToString value instead of the object itself (and also returns the index of the successful find as I found that useful too). I don't want to explicitly specify the type of list which is why I made it (Of T), and I want to just compare the string value rather than the instance of the object itself because I found it always returns false otherwise because the instance of the object is always going to be different.

> Include this extension somewhere accessible

```
<Extension>
Public Function ContainsText(Of T)(ByVal ObjectList As List(Of T), _
ByVal Match As T, Optional ByRef Location As Integer = -1) As Boolean
    For i = 0 To ObjectList.Count - 1
        If ObjectList(i).ToString.Equals(Match.ToString) Then
            Location = i
            Return True
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

> Then call it like this

```
'Convert GetFiles array into list
Dim fList As List(Of FileInfo) = d.GetFiles.ToList

'Use the above extension to try to find within it a string value that matches f.ToString
If fList.ContainsText(f) Then
    Debug.Print("Success")
Else
    Debug.Print("No Success")
End If
```

I would expect the final result to be successful but alas it does not appear to be the case.

Comment: Change it like this and you will get the name with path: Debug.Print(fi.FullName)

Comment: Ran into the same issue with fi.ToString() and used FullName instead

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Reference Source for `FileInfo`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filesysteminfo.cs,fbba9dab19204e29,references)

`ToString` just returns the value from an internal `DisplayPath` property. That property is set several different ways, depending on where the `FileInfo` instance was initialized.

It isn't clear from the source code *why* it is set different, and we will probably never know for sure unless one of the Microsoft developers who designed it tells us.

`DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` eventually routes through [`FileSystemEnumerator`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filesystemenumerable.cs,e9aaa9fc3bf05462) which looks fairly complex, as far as dealing with the path; it may yield more clues.

Comment: Ah, a reason which is good but decidedly inconvenient. I was hoping someone would just say "yeah just set the DisplayPath and you're all set" lol no such luck.

Answer (score 0):

Why not change your if?

```
    If fList.Select(Function(fn) fn.FullName).ToList.ContainsText(f.FullName) Then
        Debug.Print("Success")
    Else
        Debug.Print("No Success")
    End If
```

Comment: That if statement was only an example to allow you to recreate the problem - it's not actually part of my application. My aim is to make the extension work when it is calling the ToString function of a List item (Of T). If I try to change it to FileInfo inside the extension then it won't work as a List(Of T), I'll have to make a separate function for each kind of list which defeats the purpose of having the extension.

Comment: Did you try the code I posted?  In this case the (Of T) was strings and ContainsText should have worked.  As I recall I did test it.

Comment: It may well work but I opted for the GetFileList extension-style work-around so the main lines of application code are more readable (to me). All that Select and Function kinda did my head in a fraction as I'm rather unfamiliar with those usages, but that could still help someone else one day.
Also couldn't quite get where fn came from, did you mean fi?

Comment: fn was just the name of each fileinfo being enumerated by the select.  It could have been fi, or foo, or whatever name you wanted.  You seemed adamant about using the generic extension, but the answer was a differnet approach entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I devised this work-around after realising the problem was out of my hands, but in case anyone else wants their ToString to match their FullName after calling GetFiles, then you need an additional wrapper for calling GetFiles.

> This returns a list where as GetFiles() returns an array, but this was most logical for the application

```
<Extension>
Public Function GetFileList(ByVal d as DirectoryInfo, _
Optional byVal SearchPattern as String = "") As List(Of FileInfo)
    GetFileList = New List(Of FileInfo)
    If d IsNot Nothing AndAlso d.Exists Then
        For Each f As FileInfo In d.GetFiles(SearchPattern)
            'Add to new list using only file path
            GetFileList.Add(New FileInfo(f.FullName))
        Next
    End If
End Function
```

Of course this can be adapted further to include search options but this was enough to make the comparison in the ContainsText extension work correctly

Cheers for the input